# Mixed HTTP / HTTPS content with Gitlab behind a reverse proxy

Tags: redirect, nginx, docker, proxy, gitlab

I'm running `sameersbn/docker` behind a nginx reverse proxy, but I get a mixed content warning on the avatar image.

No matter what I try, it is either the **mixed content** warning or a **too many redirects** error page.

I forward my http traffic automatically in nginx with this config:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com;
    return 301 https://myserver.com$request_uri;
}

server
{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate myserver.cert.combined;
    ssl_certificate_key myserver.key;
    include nginx_php.conf;

    location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto: https;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl: on;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10080;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/webapps.ssl.conf;
}
```

As soon as I run my gitlab container with the following options, I get the **too many redirects**

```
- GITLAB_HTTPS=true
- SSL_SELF_SIGNED=false

- GITLAB_HOST=myserver.com
- GITLAB_PORT=443
- GITLAB_SSH_PORT=22
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
And why does Gitlab try to load the avatar over http?